# 400 Bad Request

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I try to use `cloudfoundry` first time.

I created a simple application in `grails` and installed `cloud-foundry` plugin. Plugin is installed correctly. I was trying to run `prod cf-push` command but received this error. Any ideas about this error ?

```
org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request (Invalid application description)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth trying with VMC (if you have it installed).

Package your Grails app

```
grails prod war
```

then deploy with vmc

```
vmc push [app name here] --path target/
```

follow the interactive prompts, but VMC should recognise the war file as a Grails app